# TFS MSProject mapping deadline date

Tags: tfs, ms-project, tfs-workitem

We have a workitemtype in TFS2012, and I created a mapping.xml to map fields with the MSProject, which was working well till I wanted to map the pjTaskDeadline.

So the problem is that, I want to map a deadline field which type is date with the Deadline field in the MSProject, so I add this row to the mapping.xml:

```
<Mapping WorkItemTrackingFieldReferenceName="myProj.DeadlineDate" ProjectField="pjTaskDeadline"/>
```

When I try to upload the file I get this error:

> TF233003: Cannot upload the specified file as it either contains invalid elements or the elements are not in the correct sequence. Correct the Team Foundation Server Field Mapping file and try again.
>
> Error detail:
>
> TF234000: Work item field myProj.DeadlineDate is mapped to the wrong field type in Microsoft Project. You can map work item fields of type DateTime only to Microsoft Project fields of type DateTime. Map the work item field to a Microsoft Project field of type DateTime.

I search for a solution [on the internet and found only this one.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/06155023-62e9-4cbf-8788-bcf379994c0d/mapping-microsoftvstsschedulingduedate-to-pjtaskdeadline-gives-error?forum=tfsprojectsrvint)

I found that the pjTaskDeadline can be refreshed only from MSProj to TFS, so I added to the xml row this: PublishOnly="true", but still get the same error.

```
<Mapping WorkItemTrackingFieldReferenceName="myProj.DeadlineDate" ProjectField="pjTaskDeadline" PublishOnly="true"/>
```

If I change the work item field type to string it's working well, but the problem is that, I cannot create query in the TFS like `myProj.Deadline > @Today - 7`, because it's not a datetime type.

Could you help me, how can I map a DateTime type work item field with the msproj pjTaskDeadline?

Comment: This seams to be a bug with the Project Field pjTaskDeadline: I open a ticket @ [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/34146/mapping-microsoftvstsschedulingtargetdate-to-pjtas.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/34146/mapping-microsoftvstsschedulingtargetdate-to-pjtas.html) Please go vote!